# XPCOM for safari and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, safari, adblock

Adblock Plus uses XPCOM to block ads requests i.e., using content policy object. It seems like XPCOM is available only for firefox browser. How does Adblock plus do the same for chrome and safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can study the source code of Adblock Plus: https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome

I guess the high-level answer would be [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) (and its upcoming update [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest)), which allows to intercept requests and deny/modify them.